# Enter the CSS property and change after refresh,still can not fix it

Tags: javascript, html, css

new to Javascript,and is learning CSS tricks recently,.I write the script below ,this code is used to change the text style instantly after refreshing according to the property and value you enter,but it won't work,and I can not sort it out.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>CSS Dictionary</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var property;
            var value;
            var paragraph;
            function property_convert(property)
            {   
                /*this function will change ,for example text-align to textAlign*/
                var index=property.indexOf('-');
                var firstString=property.substring(0,index);
                var middleString=property.substring(index+1,index+2).toUpperCase();
                var lastString=property.substr(index+2);

                var convertedProperty=firstString+middleString+lastString;
                return convertedProperty;
            }

            function getPropertyandValue_onclick()
            {

                property=document.getElementById('txtProperty').value;
                while(property.lastIndexOf('-') !=-1)
                {
                    property=property_convert(property);
                }

                value=document.getElementById('txtValue').value;
                paragraph=document.getElementById('paragraph');
                alert("Property:"+property+" Value:"+value);

            }
            function changeStyle_onclick()
            {
                paragraph.style.property=value; /*this code won't work ，change the property to */
            }

        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            p{
                text-underline-position:below;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>See the change in the following two paragraphs</h1>
        <p id="paragraph">CSS is very useful in web designing,and a powerful tool when combining with JavaScript ,hope you will enjoy the show.<br />
        Forget the easy way,learn web design the hard way.</p>

        <br />
        <br />
        Property:
        <input type="text" id="txtProperty">
        Value:
        <input type="text" id="txtValue">
        <input type="button" id="txtAddPropertyValue" value="add this property" onclick="getPropertyandValue_onclick()">
        <input type="button" id="btnClick" value="click to see" onclick="changeStyle_onclick() ">

        <br />
        if you have something to tell me,please email me
        <a href="mailto:caozi542@gmail.com">caozi542@gmail.com</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

`paragraph.style.property=value` this will access the key "property" of style object and not the value of property, try this instead:

`paragraph.style[property] = value;`

EDIT: An example:

```
var obj = {
    prop1: "somevalue",
    prop2: "anothervalue",
    property: "thirdvalue"
}

var property = "prop1";

console.log(obj.property);   // => "thirdvalue"
console.log(obj[property]);  // => "somevalue"
```

Comment: Can You explain it in more broader fashion ? @caeth

Comment: @surajrawat I've added an example.